# Python wrapper amazon product api

Tags: python, amazon-product-api

I was trying to install the following python wrapper for Amazons product api: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-amazon-product-api/0.2.5a1

I'm getting an error "File "setup.py", line 3, in 
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools" once I run the setup.py script. I was wondering if there is something I'm doing wrong. Also, is there some other python wrapper you guys would recommend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install SetupTools first:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads